# Telescope on Meteor running error

Tags: meteor, telescope

I'm currently trying to run Telescope on Meteor. I've installed meteor as well and cloned Telescope in my Documents folder. However, when I run 'meteor' on Telescope, I get this error:

```
*Renzzes-MacBook-Air:Telescope renzzemistal$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Documents/Telescope ]]]]]             
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
telescope:email: updating npm dependencies -- html-to-text...
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-zf7sqf@0.0.0 No
description
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-zf7sqf@0.0.0 No
repository field.
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-zf7sqf@0.0.0 No README
data
npm WARN engine html-to-text@0.1.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.8.0"} (current:
{"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3',
npm ERR!   parent: 'html-to-text' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! command
"/Users/renzzemistal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/Users/renzzemistal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"install"
npm ERR! cwd
/Users/renzzemistal/Documents/Telescope/packages/telescope-email/.npm/package-new-yrsnn6
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3'
npm ERR! not ok code 0
telescope:newsletter: updating npm dependencies -- html-to-text...
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-9t1t7p@0.0.0 No
description
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-9t1t7p@0.0.0 No
repository field.
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-9t1t7p@0.0.0 No README
data
npm WARN engine html-to-text@0.1.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.8.0"} (current:
{"node":"0.10.36","npm":"1.4.28"})
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3',
npm ERR!   parent: 'html-to-text' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! command
"/Users/renzzemistal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/Users/renzzemistal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"install"
npm ERR! cwd
/Users/renzzemistal/Documents/Telescope/packages/telescope-newsletter/.npm/package-new-8pwb46
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir
'/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/underscore.string/2.3.3'
npm ERR! not ok code 0
telescope:post-by-feed: updating npm dependencies -- feedparser, to-markdown,
he, iconv-lite...
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-cjzir1@0.0.0 No
description
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-cjzir1@0.0.0 No
repository field.
npm WARN package.json packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-cjzir1@0.0.0 No README
data
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/iconv-lite/0.4.7'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/iconv-lite/0.4.7']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/iconv-lite/0.4.7',
npm ERR!   parent: 'packages-for-meteor-smartpackage-cjzir1' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! command
"/Users/renzzemistal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node"
"/Users/renzzemistal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm"
"install"
npm ERR! cwd
/Users/renzzemistal/Documents/Telescope/packages/telescope-post-by-feed/.npm/package-new-ah6u81
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /Users/renzzemistal/.npm/iconv-lite/0.4.7
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/Users/renzzemistal/.npm/iconv-lite/0.4.7'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!
/Users/renzzemistal/Documents/Telescope/packages/telescope-post-by-feed/.npm/package-new-ah6u81/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
telescope:rss: updating npm dependencies -- rss...
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While building package telescope:email:
   error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap

   While building package telescope:newsletter:
   error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap

   While building package telescope:post-by-feed:
   error: couldn't install npm packages from npm-shrinkwrap

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.*
```

Did I miss something? Or should I install it somewhere else?

Appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EACCES` is a common error associated with lacking the appropriate permissions. Try running the command again as root:

```
sudo meteor
```